# User Defined Runtime Attributes accessibility

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I created a User Defined Runtime Attributes to my custom UIView in IB, and the interesting thing is, that I can access it in touchesBegan:withEvent: method but not in initWithCoder: Do you know why?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the views from IB are finished loading after `initWithCoder`. The following will help you understand the process. It is explained for `UIViewControllers`, but the concept is the same (from the [ViewController Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)):

> When you create a view controller in a storyboard, the attributes you
>   configure in Interface Builder are serialized into an archive. Later,
>   when the view controller is instantiated, this archive is loaded into
>   memory and processed. The result is a set of objects whose attributes
>   match those you set in Interface Builder. The archive is loaded by
>   calling the view controller’s initWithCoder: method.

Comment: By this description, the runtime attributes *should* be accessible from the coder object passed to `initWithCoder`. They will clearly not be accessible on the object, because this is an init method and it has not been created yet. How does one access these attributes from the coder object?

Answer (score 11):

If you need to access the values when setting up your view instead of processing it in `initWithCode:` use `awakeFromNib`